# debugging the javascript function

Tags: javascript

I wanted to get all the information related to episode number and season given by the user but it isnt working

https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/edwisor-india-bucket/assignments/we
b03/JSS1l2/bigbangtheory.json

```
let obtain=(season,episode)=>

{
  var seasonfound=false
  var episodefound=false
  for (var i of information.embedded.episode)
  {
    if(information.embedded.episode[i].season==season)
    {
      if(information.embedded.episode[i].number==episode)
      {
        seasonfound=true
        episodefound=true
         break
      }
      else{
        seasonfound=true
        episodefound=false
        break
      }
    }
    else
    {
      seasonfound=false
    }
  }
  if (seasonfound==true && episodefound==true)
  {

    alert(info[i].id)
  }
  else{
    alert('incorrect')
  }



     }



let S=window.prompt('enter the seaseon you wish')

let E=window.prompt('enter the episode you wish')

obtain(S,E)
```

Comment: Not working how?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your link to the JSON isn't correctly formatted.